# Bash Script add, delete, users, directories and files

Tags: linux, bash

hi guys I need to create a bash scrip for my class and I haven't taken any classes that teach how to this yet. The bash script menu has to have the following:

```
Please choose one of the following option:
a- Create a File
b- Create a Directory
c- Delete a File
d- Delete a Directory
e- Create a User
f- Delete a User
q- Quit 


Enter your choice: a
     What would you like to name your file (including the path to the location to where you want the file to be): ~/Data
     ~/Data: File Created successfully.
Enter your choice: q
```

I've try to do search on my own but since I've never done it before I don't know where to start. I know how to execute it at least and i know how to do all of this with the commands but I have no idea how to create the bash script file. I would appreciate the help and some explanation so I can at least try to understand this. My class is using the newest version of fedora if that helps. Also the professor wants us to use nano for it

Comment: Did the professor provide documentation as well?

Comment: she just gave us 4 web site links for information but I've only had one class about programming and it was WBScripting and I struggle with the class. I've try to understand what is going on and all but so far I've only been able to learn how to create, and give passwords and deleting by looking on the web a lot and its hard since I don't know what I'm doing. Also I'm testing this in a simulation lab that my school provides. I need help with this

Comment: Also we had 2 options do a 10-15 page report the benefits of choosing Linux based OS for a company or this bash script. Since I'm have little knowledge about scripting and I'm bad at it, I wanted to take this chance and learn more about it.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with a 10-15 page report? Research and writing included, your looking at an hour-per-page. Piece of cake... Or,

You owe a lotta beer:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$SEL" != q ]; do
cat >&2 << MENU

  Enter a number to launch:
    a - Create a File
    b - Create a Directory
    c - Delete a File
    d - Delete a Directory
    e - Create a User
    f - Delete a User
    q - Exit
MENU
    printf "\n  Enter your choice: "
    read SEL
    SEL=${SEL,,}
    case $SEL in
        a ) printf "\nWhat would you like to name your File?\n"
            printf "(including the path to the file location): "
            read -r fname
            [ -n $fname ] && touch "$fname" || \
            printf "error: invalid filename.\n"
            unset fname
            ;;
        b ) printf "\nWhat would you like to name your Directory?\n"
            printf "(including the path to the directory location): "
            read -r dname
            [ -n $dname ] && mkdir -p "$dname" || \
            printf "error: invalid directory name.\n"
            unset dname
            ;;
        c ) printf "\nWhat File would you lime to delete?\n"
            printf "(including path): "
            read -r fname
            [ -w "$fname" ] && rm "$fname" || \
            printf "error: invalid filename or insufficent permission.\n"
            unset fname
            ;;
        d ) printf "\nWhat Directory would you lime to delete?\n"
            printf "(including path): "
            read -r dname
            [ -d "$dname" -a -w "$dname" ] && rm -r "$dname" || \
            printf "error: invalid directory or insufficent permission.\n"
            unset dname
            ;;
        e ) printf "\nEnter user name to add: "
            read -r uname
            [ -n $uname ] && useradd $uname
            unset uname
            ;;
        f ) printf "\nEnter user name to delete: "
            read -r uname
            [ -n $uname ] && userdel $uname
            unset uname
            ;;
        q ) exit 0
            ;;
        * ) printf "\nError. Please enter a valid selection.\n"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

**Note:** you make sure you return the favor to someone in need in the future...

Comment: His professor will be impressed with his knowledge.

Comment: I would be impressed if someone showed me this for their first assignment.  Heredocs are somewhat advanced. In any case, the script is very well written. On a side note, did you mean to `echo` instead of `printf` in your * case?

Comment: Thanks, but I meant, do you think the professor will buy the fact it came from him? `:)`  (no, `printf` was intentional - much more format control.)

Comment: I was hinting at a no. xD Yes, I realize `printf` is usually preferred, which is why I asked why you `echo` in your * case of your switch statement.

Comment: I want to see his profession figure out `SEL=${SEL,,}`

Comment: Yes `${var,}` forces the first occurrence of an upper case to lower, `${var,,}` forces all occurrences to lower, and `${var,, [AEIOU]}` will only change the characters found in the character case (vowels here) to lower.

Comment: Gotta love builtins. :D

Comment: This script look really well done not that I would know but I've research some online and I've seen the use of echo but your using printf. I know you talk about it on the comments a little but I would like to know more about the difference. Also for the error when you state that invalid or insufficient permission, you mean that it will ask the user to log into root in order to do this action?. Finally thank you for the responses, I won't forget and I would return the favor and thank you for helping.

Comment: `printf` and `echo` both write to `stdout` (the terminal screen) and both work with any shell. `echo` is quite limited in terms of format control. In fact, without the `-e` option (e.g. `echo -e "stuff"`), `echo` will not even interpret common escape sequences (like `\t` for tab `\n` for newline, etc..). `printf` handles those by default. The biggest differences come in the *format string* which contains the *flags* and *format specifiers* you apply to each variable (such as specifying the width each should print in) see: [**man 3 printf**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for details.

Comment: @Alex lastly, `invalid or insufficient permission` just informs the user that they do not have sufficient permission to create or remove the file or directory. You are correct, if they want to create or remove it, they will have to log in as a user that does have sufficient permissions and run the script again. Yes, it is a well-written script. It contains a wealth of practical scripting that provide good examples of some fairly advanced topics. It's not one that would be considered beginner level.  Lend a hand when you can, if we all do, the world will be a much better place.

Answer (score 0):

I wish your teaching assistants or professors provided a little more assistance. This is a rudimentary program that might help you. This is not a means for you to submit as an answer, but for you to learn (note that I know little about bash). I do like that you took the opportunity to tackle the bash problem instead of writing a report.

Start with copying this into nano. Remove the line numbers though. That'll be a painful process. Save the file as test.sh. From command line type: `chmod 755 test.sh`. To run the program, type `./test.sh`

I'll write comments inline.

```
 1  #!/bin/bash
 2
 3  # create a function that will have echo statements
 4  # to print instructions on the screen
 5  function print_menu() {
 6  echo Please choose on of the following option:
 7  echo a - Create a file
 8  echo b - Create a directory
 9  echo c - Delete a file
10  echo d - Delete a directory
11  echo e - Create a user
12  echo f - Delete a user
13  echo q - quit
14  }
```

At this point we have written a function that can be reused by calling it using `print_menu`. You'll see as you read further.

```
15
16  # keep on looping until user presses q
17  while true; do
18
```

We want to show the print menu, then ask the user questions, based on the answer we'll do some work and then repeat the loop of showing print menu and yada yada.

```
19      # print the menu
20      print_menu
21      # ask user to choose an option
22      read -p "Enter your choice: " choice
```

So far we have shown the user the menu and asked to enter a choice. We should ideally do error checking from user input and such, but we'll cover those concepts some other time. `choice` is a variable (or bucket) that will store whatever user typed. If user typed `a`, then `choice` bucket will contain `a`. To retrieve information from that bucket, we use `$choice`

```
23      # based on user's choice, do variety of things
24      case $choice in
25          a)  read -p "Name of file to create: " file
26              touch $file
27              echo Created file $file
28              echo ----
29              ;;
```

Check out http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html for more information on how to write `case` statements in bash. We use this `case` statement to evaluate contents of bucket `$choice`.

Then we tell bash, if the choice was `a`, ask another question about file to create. Store the answer in bucket called file. And use the value contained in bucket called file by using `$file`

`touch` command creates the file. Then we provide some feedback to the user and then close out that case by typing `;;`

```
30
31          b)  read -p "Name of directory to create: " dir
32              mkdir -p $dir
33              echo Created directory $dir
34              echo ---
35              ;;
36
37          c)  read -p "Name of file to delete: " file
38              rm $file
39              echo Deleted file $file
40              echo ---
41              ;;
42
43          d)  read -p "Name of directory to delete: " dir
44              rm -rf $dir
45              echo Deleted directory $dir
46              ;;
```

All the above is just the same as choice `a`. You can add more code to handle rest of the cases.

```
47
48          q)  echo Goodbye
49              break;;
```

If the user typed `q`, we give feedback and we `break` out from the `while` loop.

```
50
51          *)  echo Nothing selected. Try again
52              ;;
```

If none of the above choices were given by the user, we will just provide feedback and go back to the top of the while loop.

```
53      esac
54      # sleep 3 seconds to give user time to digest the output
55      sleep 3
56  done
57
```

We sleep for 3 seconds and then go back to the top of while loop.

Hope this helps out.

Comment: thank you zedfoxus I appreciated how you explain things it helps a lot. I want to learn and be able to to this myself. What do you recommend I should do in order to get more use to and learn how to code more? I know you posted a link I will check it out and see. At the moment I guess I'll play with and practice.

Comment: You are most welcome. I recommend reading code, understanding the code you read and then implementing it yourself while looking at the solution as little as possible. Just look up some of the thousands of bash related questions (or any other topic that interests you), see the answers, understand it, and attempt to follow the answers yourself.

Comment: Also can you explain in more detail sleep what does it actually do I'm curios.

Comment: `sleep 3` tells the script to take rest for 3 seconds before proceeding to the next step. Take a look at this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sleep-bash-scripting/